# Conditional independence: conditioning on an empty set of random variables

Tags: mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability, terminology, independence, conditional-independence

Is $X \perp\!\!\!\perp Y$ a [conditional independence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence), arguing that the independence is conditioned on an empty set of random variables? If so, does that mean that an unconditional independence is always a conditional independence (but the converse is false)?

Comment: What is the measure of an empty set?

Comment: It might help to recognize that the sigma algebra generated by a set of random variables is the smallest sigma algebra making them all measurable. Since all sigma algebras over a set $\Omega$ must, by definition, include $\varnothing$ and $\Omega$, then your question comes down to understanding conditioning on the sigma algebra $\{\varnothing,\Omega\}$.

Comment: In a Bayesian network/DAG the joint distribution
of the $X_{1},\ldots,X_{K}$ is given by $p\left(x_{1},\ldots,x_{K}\right)=\prod_{k=1}^{K}p\left(x_{k}\mid\mathrm{Pa}\left(X_{k}\right)\right)$
where $\mathrm{Pa}\left(X_{k}\right)$ is the set of parents of $X_{k}$
(e.g., PRML by Bishop (2006, p. 362)). When there are no parents of
a paticular $X_{k}$ (meaning that $\mathrm{Pa}\left(X_{k}\right)=\left\{ \right\} $),
we effectively have the situation of conditioning on an emtpy set
and (here) it is interpreted as $p\left(x_{k}\mid\mathrm{Pa}\left(X_{k}\right)\right)=p\left(x_{k}\right)$.

Comment: @whuber Do you think that the machine learning literature is wrong in using this interpretation or am I missing something?

Comment: @statmerkur AFAIK, everybody understands a "conditional" probability with no conditioning variable simply to be an (unconditional) probability. (Some) Bayesians insist [all probabilities are conditional,](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27987/are-all-probabilities-conditional-probabilities) but they do so by imagining conditioning events in every probability statement, whether or not those events are given explicitly.

Comment: @whuber Doesn't this imply that the OP`s proposition is basically right?

Comment: @statmerkur That's exactly what Kjetil Halvorsen's answer argues.  (I am surprised nobody besides me has upvoted it.)

Comment: @whuber Mhm Kjetil Halvorsen is talking about conditioning on the whole sample space. Isn't that the opposite of conditioning on an empty set?

Comment: @statmerkur It is exactly the same thing as conditioning on the empty set.  That's because conditioning depends on the entire sigma algebra and, whenever a set is in the algebra, so is its complement--and the sample space is the complement of the empty set.  This is the same remark I made at the outset of this comment thread.

Comment: @whuber That makes sense. Admittedly, I wasn't thinking hard enough about your first comment in this thread. Thanks for clarifying this.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I would say, $X \perp\!\!\!\perp Y$ can be thought of as conditional independence, but conditioning on the full sample space $\Omega$. The probability of the empty set *impossible event* is zero, and you cannot really condition on an event with probability zero.

Conditioning on the full sample space really is saying that "the only fact that I know is that some outcome in the sample space happened", as it must if your model is any good.